# Possible to get field-names based on a condition in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I found that the GetMapping API can give me all field-names (i.e. keys) in ES, but it doesn't have a way to filter results by a condition. Is there a way to say give me all field-names where customerID = foo123?

---

**Context**: I'm making a search UI which only supports field-based searching (no full-text support) where the user can use "filters" (see mock UI below) to find what they're looking for.

**Goal**: 
**I want to populate the "Field-names" dropdown**. Which would be straightforward by calling GetMapping, but I can't put a condition on it. My ES cluster is multi-tenant, and in my search UI I only want to show field-names for the customer using it.

**What the UI looks like**: Run the snippet below to see a mock I made to help you visualize

```html
Field-name:
<select>
  <option>appName</option>
  <option>rules.myRule.fired</option>
  <option>rules.notMyRule.fired</option>
</select>

Operator:
<select>
  <option>=</option>
  <option>!=</option>
</select>

Value: <input type="text" value="true" width=1/>
<br/> Field-name:
<select>
  <option>appName</option>
  <option>rules.myRule.fired</option>
  <option>rules.notMyRule.fired</option>
</select>

Operator:
<select>
  <option>=</option>
  <option>!=</option>
</select>
Value: <input type="text" value="true" width=1/>
<br/>(+) Add more filters<br/>
<button>Search</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to separate the customers to different indexes. This is also good in case the data and fields for each customer is different. If each customer would have its own index, then getting the fields of a customer can be done using the GET Mapping api directly, without needing another filter.

A second option would be to hold records (stateful) for each customer - which fields it is sending. This can be done in ES index or on any other DB/cache.

A third option would be to bring X docs for a specific customer ID using search API, and then run over all those docs and collect the field names in them - this might not be the full list, as you are checking only X docs, but if X is big enough and the docs repeat their structure, then that might be good enough.